# Nodejs api rest test with mocha and chai. Post pending

Tags: node.js, rest, mocha.js, integration-testing, chai

I'm learning to do api rest tests and I came across a problem using chai and mocha, I was following [this example](https://medium.com/@rafaelvicio/testando-api-rest-com-mocha-e-chai-bf3764ac2797).

The problem is that the POST method is always pending, according to something pending it does not mean that it failed. But I would like to pass this test.
My route is returning a `json` of what was created, so I didn't understand why the test didn't pass, can someone help me with that?

Link to the [repository](https://github.com/ThiagoBussola/api-games) if it helps.

POST route code

```
router.post("/game", async (req, res) => {
    const title = req.body.title
    const year = req.body.year
    const price = req.body.price
    try {
       const gameCreated = await Game.create({
            title: title,
            year: year,
            price: price
        })
        res.json(gameCreated)
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }
})
```

Test code

```
describe("POST game test", () => {
    it("must create a new game"), (done) => {

        let game = {
            title: "Game created by mocha",
            year: 2020,
            price: 178
        }
        chai.request('localhost:3033')
            .post('/game')
            .send(game)
            .end((err, res) => {
                res.should.have.status(200)
                
                done()
            })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your test, you have to write like this:

```js
it("must create a new game", (done) => {
```

But you have

```js
 it("must create a new game"), (done) => {
```

Note the `)` different

Comment: Thank you my friend, you helped me, now it's working! as i am having a different error in getById i will open another topic. Thank you for your help.